# Java Graphics Not Displaying In OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swing

I'm a Computer Science student who uses a mid-2009 MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3. I recently had a class activity in my Object-Oriented programming class where we went step-by-step in creating an interactive Java program in which the user simply clicks a football and watch it get kicked over the goalpost with a green background.

However, even though my Java code matched the code of my classmates' Windows computers with no syntax errors, there are some problems with my program properly running while theirs work perfectly fine:

While the window for the application opens with the title and green background, neither the football nor goalpost is displayed. However, if I manually stretch the window, they show back up. I've tried changing the window dimensions to see if that was causing it to no avail.

When the football is clicked, instead of moving towards the goalpost as intended, both the football and goalpost vanish and don't return. Only the green background is displayed, even when I try manually stretching the window again.

I still submitted the code to my instructor, which worked fine on his computer (he doesn't understand the problem either since he doesn't use OS X). I tried to run the code on two other IDE's to see if Eclipse was the problem, but they all produced the same results. If this is an OS X or computer-exclusive problem, how am I able to get around this?

This is my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Football extends JFrame {

   final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
   final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

   private int x = 40;                // Ball's X coordinate
   private int y = 300;               // Ball's Y coordinate
   private final int WIDTH = 35;      // Ball's width
   private final int HEIGHT = 60;     // Ball's height

   private final int X_MOVE = 14;     // Pixels to move ball
   private final int Y_MOVE = 4;

   private final int TIME_DELAY = 25; // Time delay
   private Timer timer;               // Timer object

   /**
      init method
   */

   public Football() {
       setTitle("Football");
       setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setVisible(true);

       // Set Background to a Dark Green
       getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 220, 50));         

       // initTimer();
       addMouseListener(new FbMouseListener());
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      // Call the superclass paint method.
      super.paint(g);  
      // Set the color to Brown
      g.setColor(new Color(129, 74, 25));

      // Draw the football
      g.fillOval(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      // Draw the Goalpost
      g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
      g.fillRect(670, 240, 5, 140);
      g.fillRect(610, 80, 5, 140);
      g.fillRect(740, 120, 5, 140);
      // Need Thicker line
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
      g2.drawLine(612, 220, 742, 260);
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Update the ball's position
        y -= Y_MOVE;
        x += X_MOVE;

        // Force a call to the paint method
        repaint();  
    }

   }

   public void initTimer()
   {
       timer = new Timer(TIME_DELAY, new TimerListener());
       timer.start();
   }

   private class FbMouseListener implements MouseListener
   {
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
       {
           if (e.getX() >= x && e.getX() <= (x + WIDTH) && e.getY() >= y && e.getY() <= (y + HEIGHT))
           {
               initTimer();
           }
       }

       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

       public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Football fb = new Football();
   }

}
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, as I would like to make sure this doesn't affect any future programs I create.

Comment: Generally, overriding `paint` of a top level container like `JFrame` is a bad idea, `JFrame` contains a bunch of child components that can be painted independently of the parent, which seems to be the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, overriding `paint` of a top level container like `JFrame` is a bad idea, `JFrame` contains a bunch of child components that can be painted independently of the parent, which seems to be the case here

[image: RootPane]

As you can see, there are (at least) 3 other components in between the frame and the user

Generally, you should create a custom class which extends from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` and perform your custom painting there.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Football {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Football();
    }

    public Football() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Football");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new FootballPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class FootballPane extends JPanel {

        public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
        public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;

        private int x = 40;                // Ball's X coordinate
        private int y = 300;               // Ball's Y coordinate
        private static final int WIDTH = 35;      // Ball's width
        private static final int HEIGHT = 60;     // Ball's height

        private static final int X_MOVE = 14;     // Pixels to move ball
        private static final int Y_MOVE = 4;

        private static  final int TIME_DELAY = 25; // Time delay
        private Timer timer;               // Timer object

        /**
         * init method
         */
        public FootballPane() {

            // Set Background to a Dark Green
            setBackground(new Color(0, 220, 50));

            // initTimer();
            addMouseListener(new FbMouseListener());

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // Call the superclass paint method.
            super.paintComponent(g); 

            // Set the color to Brown
            g.setColor(new Color(129, 74, 25));

            // Draw the football
            g.fillOval(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            // Draw the Goalpost
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(670, 240, 5, 140);
            g.fillRect(610, 80, 5, 140);
            g.fillRect(740, 120, 5, 140);
            // Need Thicker line
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            g2.drawLine(612, 220, 742, 260);
        }

        private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Update the ball's position
                y -= Y_MOVE;
                x += X_MOVE;

                // Force a call to the paint method
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public void initTimer() {
            timer = new Timer(TIME_DELAY, new TimerListener());
            timer.start();
        }

        private class FbMouseListener implements MouseListener {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getX() >= x && e.getX() <= (x + WIDTH) && e.getY() >= y && e.getY() <= (y + HEIGHT)) {
                    initTimer();
                }
            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }

    }

}
```

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Thanks, that got it working properly. However, I'm still curious as to why the same program I originally created worked fine on other peoples' Windows OS computers but not my OS X computer.

Comment: Essentially, it was luck.  There is enough differences between how MacOS renders it's contents and Windows to allow the Windows implementation to avoid some of the issues.  You'd probably be able to force it to occur on Windows if your resided the window...